# Wordpress will not operate correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database

My website is [ImASpy.com](http://www.imaspy.com). If you click on the link, Findings, this takes you to my first Wordpress page. It appears to work fine until you click on comments, or you try to go to the about page, which is another Wordpress page. it stops working and usually gives a database error. Even worse, I cannot get into my Wordpress administration. Any idea what's going on? If you need details please let me know what you need. I can give you the entire Sql file or the wp-config.php if you need it. Thanks!

Comment: when you migrated the database, did you update the URLs?

Comment: Yes I did update them.

Comment: It also happens with me i don't get why its happening but i deleted config file and install it again with same db so it works fine and also didn't lost any content .

Comment: nope you didn't :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably messed up with the config on the DB

I would like the dump of the config table please, that way i can see the paths to your wp install (i had a similar problem which i solved by manually correcting the fields in DB)

**EDIT**

Run this sql query and let me know :

```
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress' WHERE `option_name` = 'siteurl' OR `option_name` = 'home'
```

Comment: It's weird, since `/wp-admin` is a 404

Comment: This was working fine on my local server. I just put all the files live and it hasn't worked since. So you want the sql file i exported from my local server then imported to my live server?

Comment: I don't know what "dump of the config table" means. What do you need?

Comment: sorry for being too technical, but yes i need the sql file
please upload it some place and put the link here instead of copy pasting it :)

Comment: wow it's pretty massive... you can see it here... http://www.imaspy.com/imaspy.sql

Comment: i updated my answer, try it out and let me know :)

Comment: I did a whole crap load of work to fix this but your solution was the problem and everything works fine now! woo too!

Comment: im glad you fixed it then :)

Answer (score 1):

First decide which url you are going to use. The actual files are on http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress/ url. So you have to use that inorder use your wordpress. If you want to use the main domain url then you have to transfer all the files from the wordpress folder to the main root folder. Also change the following values to the database.

Table name: wp_options

Fileds: siteurl and home

The value should not be imaspy/wordpress

It should be http://www.imaspy.com/wordpress or the main domain name (You have to choose which location you are going to use.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out but the first guy helped me first.

Comment: Thats ok. the main thing is to solve the problem and i am happy that it is solved. Thanks